# Send Paypal IPN to a secondary email (NOT the primary) How?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

My developer is trying to get the instant payment notifications for one of my web products to be sent to a secondary email, not the primary Paypal one. But no luck so far -it keeps getting sent to my primary email. I'd like some help on how to get it sent to a secondary email account?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your email address doesn't have anything to do with where the IPN gets sent.  You basically have 2 options for configuring IPN.

1) Log in to the PayPal account that is receiving the payments, go into the profile, and then into Instant Payment Notification Preferences.  Enable it, and add the URL to your IPN listener.  This will now act as a default IPN listener so every transaction that hits your PayPal account will send an IPN to this URL.

2) If you include a notify URL in your button code or API calls this will override what you have setup in your profile.  If you need to send IPN's for a specific button or API call to a secondary IPN listener you can just add that URL to the notify value for the request and that's where the IPN's will go.

If you need IPN's to hit multiple scripts you might want to take a look at this article I wrote awhile back about [daisy-chaining PayPal IPN scripts](http://www.angelleye.com/how-to-daisy-chain-paypal-ipn-messages/).

Comment: But how can we receive email from paypal to secondary or any other email, the "Notification of Payment Received" email paypal sends after payment?

Comment: the generic notification that PayPal's system sends will go to the email address on file with the account.  You'll need to setup IPN as I explained in this answer to generate your own email notifications which could be sent to any email address(es) you want.